# how to create a log in window where my username and password is from a server?

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have this html and javascript program code for log in window. my html is:

```
<body>
  <div >
    <h1>Sign in to me</h1>      
    <form id="login" method="get" action='exercises/exercise6/DynamicMenu_createTab_json.html'>
       <div>UserName<input type="text" id="username" value="admin"/></div>
       <div>Password<input type="password" id="password"/></div>  
       <div><input type="button" id="btnLogin" value="Login"/></div>
  </div>    
</body>
```

my javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#username').focus();
    $('form#login :submit').addClass('inputSubmitBtn').click(function(){
       if($('#username').val() != "jay" || $('#password').val() != "son"){
           alert('username/password incorrect');    
           $("#username").focus();
           return false;
       };
    });
});
```

there's no problem in this program. what i wanted to do is i want to log in using my username and password from a server. and if it is succesful, it will open my other exercise html on the same window. here's my current code:

```
$('form#login :submit').addClass('inputSubmitBtn').click(function(){
    var params = {
       "UserName":$("#username").val(),
       "Password":$("#password").val()
    };

    $.getJSON(
    'process.php', 'path=Login&json='  + JSON.stringify(params),  
    function(data) {
       if ('error' in data)
       {
          alert('password and username incorrect');
          return false;
       }
       else
       {
          $("#sessionID").html(data["result"]["SessionID"]);    

       }
    }); 
});
```

this code doesn't function right. please, can someone help me on this...

EDIT: here's my php code:

```
<?php 
   echo(file_get_contents("http://localhost/" . $_GET["path"] . "?json=" . $_GET["json"]));
?>
```

Comment: could you paste your PHP code?

Comment: @Lekis... there, i already paste my php. i was able to do log in but i didn't add a code to open a new html in that same window.

Comment: @ Zakaria... no error message. it's just that there no action when i clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the :submit selector returns nothing, you don't have a submit button ("type=submit"), so the click listener will never be called. See [:submit selector](http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/).

Second you don't stop the submit event of the form, so the "action" attribute is used and the form is submitted, canceling the click listener function. (url 'exercises/exercise6/DynamicMenu_createTab_json.html' will be loaded)

You need to stop the event, else the form "action" will fire when the form is submitted.

```
$('#login :submit').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); ... });
```

And last, a click event listener function on the submit button will not fire 100% of the time.
For exemple when user press "enter" key while in a field of the form, no click on the button and the form is submitted.
Bind a submit event listener on the form instead.

```
$('#login').submit(function(event){ ... });
```

Comment: when i used the :submit, it will open my other html though the username and password is incorrect

Comment: The submit event is not blocked, so you ajax call is not taken into account and the other page will be loaded.